# how make swing program wait

Tags: java, swing

basically i am writing swing program in which i am calling my swing program class through another class. Whenever i run my main class it executes and displays the swing class but even before i have pressed for OK button (Jbutton) my main class gets executed fully.
please suggest some simple ways to solve this issue as i am new to swing.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class select_common_attr1 {

    public JFrame frame;
    JCheckBox checkBoxArray[];
    public String returnstring[];
    public int set_n;
    public boolean test;
    public JButton btnOk;
    public JButton btnReset; 
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    /*public static void main(String[] args) {
        //EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            String t[]={"one","two","three"};
            //public void run() {
                //try {
            select_common_attr1 window = new select_common_attr1(t,t.length);
                    //window.print();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);

                //} catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                //}
            //}
        //});

    }*/

    public select_common_attr1(String common_attr[],int len) {
        initialize(common_attr,len);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initialize(String common_attr[],int len) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        test=false;
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 452, 263);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        checkBoxArray=new JCheckBox[len];
        for(int j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
            checkBoxArray[j]=new JCheckBox(common_attr[j]);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        {
           panel.add(checkBoxArray[i]);
        }
        btnOk = new JButton("OK");
        btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int count=0;
                for(int i=0; i<checkBoxArray.length; i++)
                {
                 if(checkBoxArray[i].isSelected())
                 {
                     count++;
                 }
                }
                set_n=count;
                returnstring=new String[set_n];
                count=0;
                for(int i=0; i<checkBoxArray.length; i++)
                {
                 if(checkBoxArray[i].isSelected())
                 {

                     returnstring[count++]=checkBoxArray[i].getText();
                 }
                }
                test=true;
                print();
            }
        });

        btnReset = new JButton("RESET");
        btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(int i=0; i<checkBoxArray.length; i++)
                {
                 if(checkBoxArray[i].isSelected())
                 {
                     checkBoxArray[i].setSelected(false);
                 }
                }
                test=false;
            }
        });
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(158)
                            .addComponent(btnOk)
                            .addGap(18)
                            .addComponent(btnReset))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 416, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(btnOk)
                        .addComponent(btnReset))
                    .addContainerGap(66, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question looks fine, but you would rather like to add a statement at the end to clearly display what you want.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want things to happen after the user pressed the OK button, you'll have to put the code in its actionListener method. This is what event listeners are for. See some background documentation here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html

And just to be precise, Java naming convention wants class names to be capital with camel case notation. That is, "select_common_attr1" should really be "SelectCommmonAttr1".
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use a modal `JDialog` instead of a `JFrame`.

This will halt the program execution until the the dialog is closed

Take a look at [How to use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for more informaiton

Answer (score 0):

You can add a lock to process your logic, please see the following code:

```
static Object lock = new Object();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    synchronized (lock) {
        String t[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
        select_common_attr1 window = new select_common_attr1(t, t.length);
        System.out.println("???????");
        try {
            lock.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("#####################");
    }
}

private void next(){
    synchronized (lock) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        lock.notify();
                    // You can process your business at here.

    }
}
private void initialize(String common_attr[], int len) {
    frame = new JFrame();
    test = false;
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 452, 263);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    checkBoxArray = new JCheckBox[len];
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        checkBoxArray[j] = new JCheckBox(common_attr[j]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        panel.add(checkBoxArray[i]);
    }
    btnOk = new JButton("OK");
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxArray[i].isSelected()) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            set_n = count;
            returnstring = new String[set_n];
            count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxArray[i].isSelected()) {

                    returnstring[count++] = checkBoxArray[i].getText();
                }
            }
            test = true;
            next();
        }
    });

    btnReset = new JButton("RESET");
    btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length; i++) {
                if (checkBoxArray[i].isSelected()) {
                    checkBoxArray[i].setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            test = false;

            next();
        }
    });

...
```